# Cant find Accella Mobile SDK IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk

I need work link to download Accella SDK for IOS. 
i found this link https://developer.accela.com/Resource/Download/QWNjZWxhIGlPUyBTREsgNC4wLnBrZw==?fileType=iOS&mimeType=application_octet-stream&displayName=Accela+iOS+SDK+V4.0. but it removed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this page https://developer.accela.com/docs/index.htm .If you can't download from this page, make letter to accela dev team.